# Python does not find the Brownie file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ethereum, solidity, brownie

I'm following a tutorial on Solidity and Python (for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=5447s).

I'm at the stage where Python and Brownie have been installed and running through VSCode, but I am getting the below notification when asking for Brownie's version  `brownie --version INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum`

When I try to run an extremely basic script on a file called deploy.py (`def main(): print ("hello!")` ), here is the result :

```
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage> brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
  importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
  network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
  rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 75, in launch
  self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 73, in launch
  return psutil.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=out, stderr=out)
File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 1312, in __init__
  self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program, line line, in in
  self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Program, line line, in in
  hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling from Python to Brownie, changing the place where Brownie's files are, but I'm now stuck due to my very limited knowledge (full beginner).

UPDATE
I've reinstalled Python and pipx and brownie once more, and now the message is slightly different, but still doesn't run the script of deploy.py. The script is :

```
def main():
    print("Hello!")
```

and the current error message is :

```
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage> brownie run scripts.deploy.py

INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 75, in launch
    self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 73, in launch
    return psutil.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=out, stderr=out)
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 1312, in __init__
    self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage>
```

Image of the directory: [image: screenshot of file location]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

After trying all suggestions, I ended up making it work only by uninstalling and removing every single program and related files.
Uninstalled Python, removed all the files related to Python from my computer, did the same for VSCode, removed all the npm packages, yarn, solc, everything related to the tutorial (I didn't have anything for coding before).

Then, reproduced all the steps until the original post issue, and everything worked fine... A bit frustrating not to know how the issue really got resolved, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deploy` script is in the `contracts` folder/directory.

It needs to be in scripts directory of your project, your `brownie_simple_storage/scripts` folder.

Try moving it there, and running your script in that folder.

EDIT:

You may need to install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [ganache-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli)

Comment: I've moved the deploy.py script to the brownie_simple_storage folder, and the error message is still the same

Comment: ah sorry, please put `deploy.py` in your `scripts` folder.

Comment: Same error message... One thing that is strange as well, is that when I type ` Python --version`  I get the version printed out nicely, but when I do the same with Brownie, I get ` INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum`. could the problem be coming from Brownie's installation folder?

Comment: No, that's fine. Do you have the ganache-cli installed?

Comment: I did, but when I checked, I receive this message : ganache-cli : 
`The term 'ganache-cli' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ganache-cli --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ganache-cli:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
Installed it again through Yarn, same error message came back

Comment: I have tried the solution found on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236378/error-in-ganache-installation-the-term-ganache-cli-is-not-recognized-as-the-n
but it still shows me the same error message

Comment: How about this?  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103490/57451

Answer (score 1):

I think since `brownie` is installed via `pipx`, you have to tell vs code for the path.

- ctrl + shift + p
- Python: select Interpreter

[image]

- Find the path in os. this is in linux

  ```
    ~/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/bin/python
  ```

I am using Linux, so find the path in your system and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Well start by downloading ganache cli using :

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

then again try running script using:

```
brownie run scripts/deploy.py
```

Hope this will work..