# Setting the path / Directory lookup for Pipx (Python 3.9 / Python 3.10)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, solidity, brownie

I was originally using Python 3.10 but experiencing some issues. I was recommended to downgrade to 3.9.8 to see if these issues still happened. After downgrading (and uninstalling Python 3.10) I installed pip and and pipx on python 3.9.8. However, when trying to install eth-brownie using pipx

```
pipx install eth-brownie
```

I experience this error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Jmclo\Documents\Demo\Python_Test> pipx install eth-brownie
No Python at 'C:\Users\Jmclo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\Jmclo\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2022-01-06_21.09.19_pip_errors.log

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

Pipx is attempting to reference the Python.exe file for Python3.10 even though it no longer exists.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled pipx as well as created the file directory location to then remove it and none of these have fixed this issue.

Any help would be great

Comment: one thing that will probably help while you're doing command line stuff from windows is to start using WSL(2) instead of windows shell

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927808/python-does-not-find-the-brownie-file/70540493#70540493

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this and it works for me:

Uninstall pipx using pip: `pip uninstall pipx`

and to completely remove pipx, u need to delete the folder at:

> C:\Users\YourUsrName\ .local\pipx

Restart your cmd terminal, and then reinstall pipx:

```
python -m pip install --user pipx
python -m pipx ensurepath
```